# i can't execute javascript given by ajax request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

i have to do a project for school but i have a problem with ajax response, this is my home page (index.php):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="it">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=chrome"/>

    <link href="stili/index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <script src="script/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>

    <title>Gestione Negozio</title>
</head>
<body>  
    <div id="navigatore">
        <a class="nav-btn" onclick="getPage('pagine/homePage.php')">HOME</a>
        <a class="nav-btn" onclick="getPage('pagine/nuovoProdotto.php')">NUOVO PRODOTTO</a>
        <a class="nav-btn" onclick="getPage('pagine/nuovaCategoria.php')">NUOVA CATEGORIA</a>
    </div>

    <div id="page">
        jhj 
        <!--loaded page will go here-->
    </div>

</body>
<script src="script/index.js"></script>
</html>
```

and this is my index.js file:

```
function getPage(pageToLoad) 
{
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() 
  {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) 
    {
      document.getElementById("page").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
  };

  xhttp.open("POST", pageToLoad, true);
  xhttp.send();
}
```

my goal is to call a page and recive both html and js.
when i call for example "nuovaCategoria.php" i receive html and js but attached js doesn't work.

this is "nuovaCategoria.php":

```
<h1>INERISCI NUOVA CATEGORIA</h1>
<form id="form">
    NOME CATEGORIA: <input type="text" name="nomeCategoria"/>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
<script>
    $('#form').submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'logica.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: $("#form").serialize(),
            success: function(msg) {
                alert('work');
            }               
        });
    });
</script>
```

i don't understand how to solve this problem.

Comment: Have you check in your browser control, if you have some errors? Also try to add an else condition in your js file

Comment: Please do a bit of basic research before you ask - this is anything but a new topic / problem, https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+not+executed+in+ajax+response+site:stackoverflow.com

Comment: Also why use XMLHttpRequest when you have `$("#page").load()`

Comment: If your page is truly that simple. Include it in the page and use .show() and .hide() instead of getting it suing Ajax

Comment: JS which is included in data downloaded via AJAX generally doesn't get executed (as a security precaution).

Comment: no, i know that using ajax in this case is unnecessary but i just wanted to try it

Comment: @mplungjan what do you mean when you say $("#page").load() ?

Comment: You can load the content of “page” using .load - read the documentation

Comment: If you receive JS from an ajax call and you attach it to your page, you need to run it with `eval()` afaik. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval

Comment: thank you @mplungjan for your advice, using .load method i can run js inside ajax response

Answer (score 0):

If I get you right, if we consider "nuovaCategoria.php" for example, you want the code in the `<script>` tag to execute. 
In that case, try rewriting the code in the `<script>` tag it like so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ //call it after the document is loaded
    $('#form').submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: 'logica.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: $("#form").serialize(),
            success: function(msg) {
                alert('work');
            }               
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: i have tried but it doesn't work